# Installing SQL problem - "Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MYSQL server at localhost:-3306

Tags: mysql, authentication, localhost, root

I cannot log in through the terminal either:

When I type in terminal: `mysql -u root -p -h localhost -p 3306`

I see the following message:

```
"Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"
```

I have tried many solutions proposed throughout the internet, with no avail. I believe, possibly, these are the problems:

1. I did not create a user with CREATE USER - I merely installed mysql, opened port 3306 through firewall,configured its installation security and created a password.
2. Maybe my router has my port blocked. I do not know how to check this, but it is very unlikely.

Comment: have you tried logging in via unix socket? try ```sudo su``` then ```mysql -u root```

Comment: Have you try w/o `-p`. By default root user have no password.  And remove `-p 3306` on the end.  Use `-P 3306` if you need to explicitly mention the port.